# How can I decline current & future events only - iCal?

Tags: calendar, ical

I want to decline current and future (recurring) events, but leave past events alone.  Apple Calendar does not give me this option in any obvious way.  How can I do this?

(Note: I could have sworn I had already asked this, but no similar question is appearing in search results.  So if this is a repeat, chalk it up to a $#!*** search engine.)